# Pausing execution of method running on UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I have a window with a browser control inside it. When someone closes the window i need to navigate the browser control to a particular URL and only after the browser is finished navigating the window needs to close.

When the window is closed the `OnBeforeWindowClose(Eventargs e)` method is called.

```
OnBeforeWindowClose(Eventargs e)
{

// As soon as the URL property is set the browser control navigates to the URL  

URL = "new URL";

//I need to wait till the browser is done navigating. Based on the NavigationFinished  property below

}

bool NavigationFinished {set; get;}
```

I cannot use `Thread.Sleep` because it will cause the UI thread to sleep. I cannot figure out a way to pause the execution of OnBeforeClose till NavigationFinised becomes true. Without blocking the UI thread.

UPDATE: Adding the following loop to the OnBeforeWindowClose method worked for me

```
do
        {
            var dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2);
            while (DateTime.Now < dateTime)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
            }
        } while (!NavigationFinished);
```

But i was wondering if there is a better way to do this instead of using the loop in .Net 4.0

Comment: You're looking for `await`.

Comment: Its not available in .net 4.0 :(

Comment: Install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` on NuGet.

Comment: I cannot use Microsoft.Bcl.Async. But the adding the below loop to the OnBeforeWindowClose method is working for me. Is there a better way to halt the method execution instead of the loop.

Comment: do
            {
                var dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2);
                while (DateTime.Now < dateTime)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                }
            } while (!NavigationFinished);

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat a work around but could work for your requirement:

- Listen to the windows closing event.
- When the Windows_Closing handler is executing then check the browser current URL: if it is not "new URL" then Cancel the closing event (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Next hook to the LoadCompleted on the Webbrowser and then set the browser URL to "new URL" and when the LoadCompleted handlers hits then call the Windows.Close() method again (you can unhook from LoadCompleted again when the browser url has already been set to "new URL" when the close method executes again).

So the idea here to achieve pause by canceling - doing something - then reclosing programatically.

Comment: The window closing is actually being called from application closing. And i cannot invoke the application closing method. i.e. i cannot programmatically reclose :( I somehow need to pause the onBeforeClose method midway and resume it after the browser has navigated.